# How to keep \n in python as character instead of new line while saving text file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of sentences, I need to add new line character and save in text file as the following format.
Note: I don't need new line character I want to keep in the given string format. I just want to keep \n and not get new line in text file
list:['Hi','I am xyz']
String Format:'Hi\nI am xyz'
If someone knows please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of Python requires you to escape the backslash so that it's not interpreted as a newline:

```py
>>> print("\n")


>>> print("\\n")
\n
```

If you string contains more newlines, having many backslashes doubled might hurt readability. In such case, you can use the raw string literals to save you escaping:

```py
>>> print(r"\n")
\n
```

Keep in mind that raw string literals **cannot end with a backslash**!

```py
>>> print(r"\")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(r"\")
          ^
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 1)
```

You can read more about this in the lexical analysis part of Python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html

Comment: Yea I can keep \n in raw strings and get the expected output but is there a way to do it in normal strings ?

Comment: There is nothing like raw literal strings and normal strings in Python. Both are normal strings, and you can combine them. If you want to join strings using a backslash and `n`, use `r"\n".join(["Hello", "World"]) `. This will return `"Hello\nWorld" `.

Answer (score 0):

In [raw strings](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-raw-string) escape characters such as `\n` won't be parsed as such, but as regular text.